# Android Firebase App class instance error

Tags: java, android

This code is a part of an firebase android app made with Android Studio. The code was written by a friend of mine and there appears a problem when trying to create instances of `Helper`, `Intent` classes with the parameter `this`. It seems that the parameter should be of `Context` type. I'm new to Java and I need help.

Class MyFirebaseMessagingService:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{
    private final String ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID = "admin_channel";
    Helper helper;

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.e("NEW_TOKEN", s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.e("FCM", "onMessageReceived");
        helper = new Helper(this);                      // Error Here
        receiveMessage(remoteMessage);

        if (helper.isLoggedIn()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirebaseChatService.class); // Error Here
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 99, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);   // Error Here
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 500, pendingIntent);
            Log.e("FCM", "scheduled");
        }
    }
```

Class Helper: (Partial Code)

```
    public Helper(Context context) {
        sharedPreferenceHelper = new SharedPreferenceHelper(context);
        gson = new Gson();
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return sharedPreferenceHelper.getStringPreference(USER) != null;
    }
```

Comment: What error you're experiencing?

Comment: @Miha_x64 Required type: ```Context```, given: ```MyFireBaseMessagingService```

Comment: Well, basically this should not happen since Services extend Context. Check your imports maybe…

Comment: My build.gradle file might be a bit problematic, I'll check it and report back. Spasibo.